# Decomposition of time series data

Tags: r, stl, forecasting

Can anybody help be decipher the output of ucm. My main objective is to check if the ts data is seasonal or not. But i cannot plot and look and every time. I need to automate the entire process and provide an indicator for the seasonality.

I want to understand the following output

```
ucmxmodel$s.season

# Time Series:
#     Start = c(1, 1) 
#     End = c(4, 20) 
#     Frequency = 52 
#       [1] -2.391635076 -2.127871717 -0.864021134  0.149851212 -0.586660213 -0.697838635 -0.933982269  0.954491859 -1.531715424 -1.267769820 -0.504165631
#      [12] -1.990792301  1.273673437  1.786860414  0.050859315 -0.685677002 -0.921831488 -1.283081922 -1.144376739 -0.964042949 -1.510837956  1.391991657
#      [23] -0.261175626  5.419494363  0.543898305  0.002548125  1.126895943  1.474427901  2.154721023  2.501352782  0.515453691 -0.470886132  1.209419689

ucmxmodel$vs.season

# [1] 1.375832 1.373459 1.371358 1.369520 1.367945 1.366632 1.365582 1.364795 1.364270 1.364007 1.364007 1.364270 1.364795 1.365582 1.366632 1.367945
# [17] 1.369520 1.371358 1.373459 1.375816 1.784574 1.784910 1.785223 1.785514 1.785784 1.786032 1.786258 1.786461 1.786643 1.786802 1.786938 1.787052
# [33] 1.787143 1.787212 1.787257 1.787280 1.787280 1.787257 1.787212 1.787143 1.787052 1.786938 1.786802 1.786643 1.786461 1.786258 1.786032 1.785784
# [49] 1.785514 1.785223 1.784910 1.784578 1.375641 1.373276 1.371175 1.369337 1.367762 1.366449 1.365399 1.364612 1.364087 1.363824 1.363824 1.364087
# [65] 1.364612 1.365399 1.366449 1.367762 1.369337 1.371175 1.373276 1.375636 1.784453 1.784788 1.785101 1.785392 1.785662 1.785910 1.786136 1.786339

ucmxmodel$est.var.season

# Season_Variance 
#     0.0001831373
```

How can i use the above info without looking at the plots to determine the seasonality and at what level ( weekly, monthly, quarterly or yearly)?

In addition, i am getting NULL in est

```
ucmxmodel$est

# NULL
```

### Data

The data for a test is:

```
structure(c(44, 81, 99, 25, 69, 42, 6, 25, 75, 90, 73, 65, 55, 
9, 53, 43, 19, 28, 48, 71, 36, 1, 66, 46, 55, 56, 100, 89, 29, 
93, 55, 56, 35, 87, 77, 88, 18, 32, 6, 2, 15, 36, 48, 80, 48, 
2, 22, 2, 97, 14, 31, 54, 98, 43, 62, 94, 53, 17, 45, 92, 98, 
7, 19, 84, 74, 28, 11, 65, 26, 97, 67, 4, 25, 62, 9, 5, 76, 96, 
2, 55, 46, 84, 11, 62, 54, 99, 84, 7, 13, 26, 18, 42, 72, 1, 
83, 10, 6, 32, 3, 21, 100, 100, 98, 91, 89, 18, 88, 90, 54, 49, 
5, 95, 22), .Tsp = c(1, 3.15384615384615, 52), class = "ts")
```

and

```
structure(c(40, 68, 50, 64, 26, 44, 108, 90, 62, 60, 90, 64, 120, 82, 68, 60,
26, 32, 60, 74, 34, 16, 22, 44, 50, 16, 34, 26, 42, 14, 36, 24, 14, 16, 6, 6,
12, 20, 10, 34, 12, 24, 46, 30, 30, 46, 54, 42, 44, 42, 12, 52, 42, 66, 40,
60, 42, 44, 64, 96, 70, 52, 66, 44, 64, 62, 42, 86, 40, 56, 50, 50, 62, 22,
24, 14, 14, 18, 18, 10, 20, 10, 4, 18, 10, 10, 14, 20, 10, 32, 12, 22, 20, 20,
26, 30, 36, 28, 56, 34, 14, 54, 40, 30, 42, 36, 52, 30, 32, 52, 42, 62, 46,
64, 70, 48, 40, 64, 40, 120, 58, 36, 40, 34, 36, 26, 18, 28, 16, 32, 18, 12,
20), .Tsp = c(1, 4.36, 52), class = "ts")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you post your data so that we can help you?

Comment: Hi Karan, it is common practice to select which answer helped you as well as up vote for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most straightforward approach would be to follow [Rob Hyndman's approach](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/detecting-seasonality/) (he is the author of many time series packages in R). For your data it would work as follows,

```
require(fma)
# Create a model with multiplicative errors (see https://www.otexts.org/fpp/7/7).
fit1 <- stlf(test2)
# Create a model with additive errors.
fit2 <- stlf(data, etsmodel = "ANN")

deviance <- 2 * c(logLik(fit1$model) - logLik(fit2$model))
df <- attributes(logLik(fit1$model))$df - attributes(logLik(fit2$model))$df

# P-value
1 - pchisq(deviance, df)

# [1] 1
```

Based on this analysis we find the *p-value* of 1 which would lead us to conclude there is no seasonality.

Comment: teste<-c(44,81,99, 25,69,42,6,25,75, 90,73,65,55,9,53, 43,19,28,48, 71,36,1,66,46,55,56,100,89,29,93,55,56,35,87,77,88,19, 8,32,6,2,15,36,48, 80,48,2,22,2,97,14,31,54,98,43,62,94,53,17,45,92,98,7,19, 84,74, 28,11,65,26, 45, 70, 88, 34, 56, 26, 32, 59, 37, 19, 87, 47, 62, 75, 39, 87, 91, 41, 39, 62, 50, 74, 54, 98, 34, 37, 85, 77, 17, 46, 49, 65, 32, 60, 11, 41, 86, 59, 96, 42, 45, 98, 86, 12, 80, 90, 33, 78, 97,67,4,95, 40, 25, 62, 5, 72, 9,5, 96, 67, 49, 34, 76,96,2,55,46,84,11, 27, 48, 31, 28,62,54,99,84, 93, 8,27,13, 26,18,42,72,1,83, 10,6,32,3,21,100,100, 98,91,89,18,88,90,54,49,5,95,22)

Comment: its a weekly data so therefore before anything you can convert it into ts(teste,freq=52)

Comment: Check [this post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/three-tips-for-posting-good-questions-to-r-help-and-stack-overflow/) on asking good `R` questions on SO.

Comment: I have tried this before but it gives the below warning message, Warning message:
In ets(test2) :
  I can't handle data with frequency greater than 24. Seasonality will be ignored. Try stlf() if you need seasonal forecasts.

Comment: Can you add that data to your post? You can output the structure with `dput()`.

Comment: structure(c(40, 68, 50, 64, 26, 44, 108, 90, 62, 60, 90, 64, 
120, 82, 68, 60, 26, 32, 60, 74, 34, 16, 22, 44, 50, 16, 34, 
26, 42, 14, 36, 24, 14, 16, 6, 6, 12, 20, 10, 34, 12, 24, 46, 
30, 30, 46, 54, 42, 44, 42, 12, 52, 42, 66, 40, 60, 42, 44, 64, 
96, 70, 52, 66, 44, 64, 62, 42, 86, 40, 56, 50, 50, 62, 22, 24, 
14, 14, 18, 18, 10, 20, 10, 4, 18, 10, 10, 14, 20, 10, 32, 12, 
22, 20, 20, 26, 30, 36, 28, 56, 34, 14, 54, 40, 30, 42, 36, 52, 
30, 32, 52, 42, 62, 46, 64, 70, 48, 40, 64, 40, 120, 58, 36, 
40, 34, 36, 26, 18, 28, 16, 32, 18, 12, 20), .Tsp = c(1, 4.36, 52), class = "ts")

Comment: With that data I'm getting `invalid time series parameters specified`

Comment: So I assumed the second time series has a frequency of `52` as your previous example. Given the new data you have indeed to use `stlf()`. I adjusted the example so that it works on both data sets. Hope this helps.

Comment: @KaranGulati if my answer worked for you  it would be appreciated if you accept the answer as solution.

Answer (score 0):

I quite like the `stl()` function provided in R. Try this minimal example:

```
# some random data
x <- rnorm(200)
# as a time series object
xt <- ts(x, frequency = 10)
# do the decomposition
xts <- stl(xt, s.window = "periodic")
# plot the results
plot(xts)
```

Now you can get an estimate of the 'seasonality' by comparing the variances.

```
vars <- apply(xts$time.series, 2, var)
vars['seasonal'] / sum(vars)
```

You now have the seasonal variance as a proportion of sum of variances after decomposition.

I highly recommend reading the [original paper](http://cs.wellesley.edu/~cs315/Papers/stl%20statistical%20model.pdf) so that you understand whats happening under the hood here. Its very accessible and I like this method as it is quite intuitive.